# How to remove an item in DropDownList in ASP MVC using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have a DropDownList, a button.

How can I remove an item from the DropDownList for each click of the button.

I try to use javascript, but I think that's not working because when I click on the button, nothing happens.

This is the code :

```
<%:Html.Label("Poste :")%>
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedPoste,
    Model.PostesItems,
    new { @id = "poste" })%>

<div>
    <input type="submit"
           value="Enregistrer"
           id="btnSave"
           onclick="remove()" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    function remove() {
        var rm = document.getElementById('btnSave');
        var poste = document.getElementById('poste');

        poste.removeItem(); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the HTML generated from your `Html.DropDownListFor` actually has an ID of "poste" and not "SelectedPoste" ?

Comment: yes,,i tried that with other JS code but to disable a dropdownlist and it s worked

Comment: May I post an answer that uses jQuery library? It would make this much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using **jQuery**

```
<select id="poste">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<br />

<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Remove current item" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            $('#poste option:selected').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: binding the click event using jQuery

Comment: @anouar Have you referenced jQuery script?

Comment: Well if you go with jquery, you might as well bind the even of the button here instead of mixing it with the html :) +1 though

Comment: @AndreCalil I don't know ? I know that the project can work with JQuery,,I don't know if there an import or something like this

Comment: @anouar You should have something like `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` somewhere

Comment: @AndreCalil hold on i will try it

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov there you go =)

Comment: @AndreCalil it's remove the button now also :(

Comment: @anouar I'm sure it's not, I've tried it. Post your complete code, please.

Comment: `remove()` is a build in JavaScript function that gets invoked on the element ... He's binding it in his HTML ... Just rename it ... Or remove it from the element if you're going to bind the event through jquery

Comment: @AndreCalil i have problem in the refreshing of the page now !!

Comment: @anouar What problem do you have? Could you please post your **entire** view code?

Comment: The item disappear when i use the solution of Dimitar but after 1 sec, the page is being refreshing and when i use your solution, the page is refreshing in the click of the button

Comment: @anouar Updated, there's a new `return false;` there now

Comment: @AndreCalil I have a problem now, Infact, the button must did an action (saving in a list) ,,,using the script of jquery,,this action disappaer :(

Comment: @anouar You must implement this action inside that `function(){...}` over there. It won't do it magically =)

Comment: @AndreCalil please look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734849/how-to-remove-an-item-in-dropdownlist-in-asp-mvc-using-ajax
because it contain the problem and i don't how to include the action in the function

Answer (score 2):

Using **vanilla JavaScript** you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function removeOption() {
       var posteElement = document.getElementById('poste');        
       var currentIndex = posteElement.selectedIndex;

       posteElement.removeChild(posteElement[currentIndex]);
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

That's all you need. Also make sure you rename your function to anything other than `remove()`:

```
<input type="submit"
       value="Enregistrer"
       id="btnSave"
       onclick="removeOption()" />
```

Check out this (not very nice [inline-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WjEXm/)).

However I'd strongly suggest at least looking into a library such as jquery, (this would be much easier than with vanilla.js). Check out Andre's answer.

Comment: `poste` is the entire `select`, not the `option`. OP wants to remove the currently selected `option`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Glad to help. +1 for the answer and for the kindness

Comment: Still the same problem :(((

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov sorry for the late,,,your solution is working but the page is refreshing after the click of the button

Comment: @anouar Ok firts of all remove you previous comments because thi thread is too long ... Second, what exactly disappeared when you're using jquery, how abou you make a fiddle with your issue and have me take a look at it

Comment: ok and please look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734849/how-to-remove-an-item-in-dropdownlist-in-asp-mvc-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment24101025_16734849

Answer (score 2):

1. The generated HTML will give the select element an ID of "SelectedPoste", not "poste" as you are attempting to set.
2. Use `remove` to remove an item.

Change your javascript to be:

```
var poste = document.getElementById('SelectedPoste');

poste.remove(poste.selectedIndex);
```

**Edit:**  The generated HTML for the select will be:

```
<select id="poste" name="SelectedPoste">...</select>
```

Either of these two lines will get that elements:

```
var poste = document.getElementById('poste');
```

or

```
var poste = document.getElementById('SelectedPoste');
```

(Atleast in IE10)

Then to remove the selected item from the list, do:

```
poste.remove(poste.selectedIndex);
```

This does not remove the button :)

**Edit 2:** Like Dimitar's answer, you need to change your function name from `remove` to something else.

Once you do that, my code above works in IE and Chrome.

Comment: please look at my code, i don't have a select, how i will put the name ?

Comment: Your `Html.DropDownListFor` will generate the <select> tag that I mention above

Comment: Google Chrome will remove the button with my javascript code above.  IE works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#poste option[value='X']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Or to be more terse, this will work just as well:

```
$("#poste option[value='X']").remove();
```

Example:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
   $("#poste option[value='X']").remove();
});
```

Remember to use **JQuery** :)