# How to remove an item in DropDownList in ASP MVC using AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

In a view, I have a DropDownList, a button.

How can I remove an item from the DropDownList for each click of the button using **AJAX.**

I did using JQuery but it cause me a problem. Infact, the button don't be able to submit (save some values in a list) anymore.

**EDIT :**

The Partial View Gestion :

```
<%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProfileGa")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

    <div>
    <%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "poste" })%>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial
    <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final
    </div>


     <div>
     <%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%>
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
      <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nbr_Passage)%>
      </div>

    <div>
    <%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Position)%>
    </div>

   <%-- <div>
   <%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PostePrecedentSelected, Model.PostesItems)%>
   </div>--%>

    <div>
    <%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "dd" })%>
    <input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="add"  onclick="addtext()"/>



   <textarea ID="ta" cols="10"  name="S1" rows="8" readonly="true"></textarea>
    </div>


    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"   />
    </div>

    </fieldset>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test() {
            var chkMain = document.getElementById('chkMain');
            var chkFirst = document.getElementById('chkFirst');


            if (chkMain.checked) {
                chkFirst.disabled = 'disabled';


            }
            else {
                chkFirst.disabled = false;

            }
        }

</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

     function test2() {
         var chkMain = document.getElementById('chkMain');
         var chkFirst = document.getElementById('chkFirst');
         var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
         var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
         var add = document.getElementById('add');

         if (chkFirst.checked) {
             chkMain.disabled = 'disabled';
             dd.disabled = 'disabled';
             ta.value = "Poste0";
             add.disabled = 'disabled';


         }
         else {
             chkMain.disabled = false;
             dd.disabled = false;
             ta.value = "";
             add.disabled = false;
         }
     }

</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var storedValues = [];
    function addtext() {

        var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
        var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
        var add = document.getElementById('add');

            var selectedValue = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value + " ";
            if (storedValues.indexOf(selectedValue) === -1) {
                storedValues.push(selectedValue)
                ta.value = storedValues.join('')
            }


    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            $('#poste option:selected').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

        <% } %>
```

The View Index :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "ProfileGa"))
   { %>

  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProfile_Ga, new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"), new { @id = "gg" })%> 
  <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" onclick="GamDis()"/>
  <input type="button" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" onclick="window.location = 'ProfileGa/Application'"/>
  </div> 

   <div id="divGestion">
   <%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %>
   </div>

       <% } %> 

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<fieldset>
<legend>Liste des Gammes</legend>


 </fieldset>
 </form>
 <input type="button" value = "Valider" /> 
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $('#btnShowGestion').click(function () { $('#divGestion').slideToggle("slow") });

     });

</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     function GamDis() {

         var gg = document.getElementById('gg');
         var bb = document.getElementById('btnShowGestion');

         if (gg.disabled) {
             gg.removeAttribute("disabled");
         } else {
             gg.disabled = 'disabled';
         }
     }
    </script>   
</asp:Content>
```

and this is the code of methode save in the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(FlowViewModel model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + model.Nbr_Passage);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Gamme G = new Gamme();
                G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
                G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;
                //G.Last_Posts = model.PostePrecedentSelected;
                G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
                G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
                G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);

                ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]).Add(G);
                var list = ((List<Gamme>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["GammeList"]);


            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                   }
```

Comment: Where is your code to save? It won't be posting back since you have returned false on the JS function.

Comment: @KingCronus sorry i forgot it,,,check my edit please and about the false , i know but if i delete it,,the page reload itself and the item of dropdownlist will not removed (which is the purpose of the function as you see)

Comment: So what is your expected behaviour? You want the button to remove an item sure...but then what?

Comment: infact, the script and the save action didn't works together. When, i delete the script, the button works perfectly and save values in a list. When, i add the script, the script works perfectly and the button remove an item from the dropdownlist without reloading the page but the submit is no more working

Comment: the two cancel each other out that's why you get that behavior. you need an async call to your code so the page doesn't reload. the solution is not to remove the item with jquery like you did above because then your save method will not be called. I hope that clears it for you a little

Comment: @anouar Please post your *complete* view code. Is that part inside a `form`?

Comment: @AndreCalil Ok but it's a lil complicated. I will explain first :
I have 2 views : Index and Gestion. Index contain a button 'Configurer' which bined in a Jquery event. When I click on 'Configurer', the partial view 'Gestion' appears (slide).
Gestion is which contain the form and button 'Enregistrer' (save)

Comment: @AndreCalil is that alright ?

Comment: @anouar *Side note*: have you ever tried Razor view engine? The syntax is so much cleaner!

Comment: @anouar About the views, there is one thing I don't understand: you have the view and the partial view both posting to the same action? I mean, there are 2 forms making the same post. You don't need that.

Comment: @anouar Besides, it's the `return false;` that's preventing the form from posting. On the other question you said *you had a problem with refresh*, that's why I added this part. If you comment this line, `btnSave` will also post the form after removing the item.

Comment: @AndreCalil I can't use Razor because the template i am using support only ASPX
2. Forget about the 2 views, it's really a BIG COMPLICATED ISSUE and i had many tired works to do it with the helps of my friends from here
3. I will try to comment and give you result,,hold on please

Comment: @AndreCalil it s the same problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30572/discussion-between-anouar-and-andre-calil)

Comment: @AndreCalil Are you here ?

Comment: @AndreCalil please check this post! this is concern the stuff that you recommand me to do it and we didn't complete it